# Anastrophe in "no copy exists of [book] "?

Tags: grammaticality, inversion

> [1.](https://books.google.coma/books?id=v-E5AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA183&dq=%22copy+exists+of%22+french&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tQ04Vd-_MciZsQT31IHIAg&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22copy%20exists%20of%22%20french&f=false) It is remarkable that no printed **copy exists of** Ovid's *Metamorphoses* ...
>
> [2.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22copy+exists+of%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=bQw4Var_EqiwsATyzICQAg#tbm=bks&q=%22copy+exists+of%22+paley) No Greek **copy exists of** either [epistle] ...
>
> [of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of) {adj} = 3. Indicating an association between two entities, typically one of belonging, in which the first is the head of the phrase and the second is something associated with it:

Does [anastrophe](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/204590/50720) apply to **exists**?
Can I move **exists** after the noun, as follows?

> 1.1. It is remarkable that no printed **copy of** Ovid's *Metamorphoses* EXISTS ...
>
> 2.1. No Greek **copy of** either [epistle]  EXISTS ...

Comment: Yes, you can move 'exists' after the noun.  I think in 2.1 it should be 'No Greek copy of either ... EXISTS'

Comment: This isn't anastrophe.  There is no "rhetorical effect".  Exists can precede or follow an of-phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the term *anastrophe* is really appropriate here, for the reason that TRomano notes above: *anastrophe* is a rhetorical figure, whereas in your examples there is no rhetorical effect.

But if you're not really asking about terminology, and are really just looking for confirmation that "of Ovid's *Metamorphoses*" is part of the subject despite appearing after the verb, then — yes, that's correct.

This phenomenon is known to linguists as *extraposition*; the phrase "of Ovid's *Metamorphoses*" is *extraposed* (pulled out of its normal position), causing a *discontinuity* in the normal original phrase "no printed copy of Ovid's *Metamorphoses*". (See ["Extraposition" on the English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) for more information about extraposition, including various other examples.)

---

As for rewriting it without extraposition . . . I find your proposals to be a bit awkward, unless there is more after the verb (e.g. "[…] exists outside of conspiracy theories"). An alternative approach might be:

> 1. It is remarkable that there exists no printed copy of Ovid's *Metamorphoses*.
> 2. There exists no Greek copy of either.

(If you are familiar with French « Il existe », then this is somewhat analogous.)